# npm fatal error on ubuntu, any idea?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have tried a lot of things, but this is still not working. When I try to run `npm start` command, it gives me this error:

```
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.4.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.6
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 start: `tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server" `
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 start script 'tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server" '.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular2-quickstart package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server" 
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs angular2-quickstart
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular2-quickstart
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/gg/Scrivania/my-proj/newangular/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: It happens when running TSC? If so, might as well tag this for typescript. Actually I just see it is for angular2

Comment: have you run `npm install` ?

Comment: yes, but every time give thats error, i Have uinstall and install but nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have some missing peer dependencies. As you are on npm version 3+ you will have to install any required peer dependencies manually.

You should see warning messages when running *npm install* to this effect. To be sure, delete node_modules and reinstall, checking the output of *npm install* carefully, as follows:

```
cd /home/gg/Scrivania/my-proj/newangular
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```